# How do I go about making a JFrame unaffected by a press of the "Show Desktop" button on the taskbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, desktop, minimize

So I've been trying to make an application that acts basically as an icon on the desktop, where it's never minimized and always stays in the back, similarly to the Keep On Top functionality of the Windows Clock where it's not changed when the Show Desktop button is pressed, except it's always sent to the back so it's on the desktop.

I've gotten many of these aspects down, except for whenever I press the Show Desktop button, everything, including my window, minimizes.

I've tried running a while loop to constantly set the window to a restored state.

I've also tried adding a `WindowStateListener` that checks if the window state has been changed, and if so, to restore it.

Neither of these stopped the Show Desktop button from minimizing them.
I tried combining these and lagged my computer out to the point of force shutdown.

Comment: There's probably no way to do this from within Java and you'll need to explore a native workflow via JNI/JNA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.